# How to Insert data from datagridview Rows to mysql database in vb.net using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

Im stucked. I am trying to insert data from the grid to the database.But I'm stucked.
[image]

Comment: Don't post just pictures of code or error messages and don't post huge screenshots when only a small part of it is relevant. ALWAYS post your code and error messages as text, formatted appropriately. Post a screenshot as well but only if it adds value. Also, if your title is longer than your post then it's a bad question. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question and then summarise that in the title. Try again.

Comment: In general terms though, you're doing it all wrong. No loops. Use a `DataTable` and a data adapter. Create a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema, populate it from the database if appropriate, bind it to the grid, make your changes as desired, then save the lot in one go with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter. There are plenty of examples around. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872)'s one I prepared earlier.

Comment: You're getting the exception because after the first row is processed you're clearing the Parameters collection. So all parameters set outside the loop are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Slugsie's comment is pertinent, but needs to go a little further:

You're actually clearing the entire parameters collection before you call the procedure. If it were a house, you went to all the effort to build the whole thing, then at the last minute you demolish it and show the customer a cleared lot

Don't clear the Parameters collection at all. Add all the parameters to it OUTSIDE the loop, then inside the loop, set the values:

```
    'general pattern
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", "...")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "...")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", "...")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param4", "...")

    For Each something In somethingElse
      cmd.Parameters("param1").Value = something.Whatever1
      cmd.Parameters("param2").Value = something.Whatever2
      cmd.Parameters("param3").Value = something.Whatever3
      cmd.Parameters("param4").Value = something.Whatever4
      cmd.Execute...
    Next something
```

That's the pattern you should be adopting

---

Though jmc also makes a useful comment; you could make your life a lot easier by

- adding a DataSet type file to your project
- open it, right click the surface, choose Add TableAdapter
- when configuring the wizard for the adapter, say you want to use stored procedures for your select, insert, update etc
- wire the procedures up to the relevant table columns

Now in code you can save data just by a single line or two:

```
Dim t as New WhateverTableAdapter
t.Update(yourWhateverDatatable) 'the WhateverDataTable is bound to a grid, the user has edited the rows in it by changing the grid
```

That Update() call will perform any necessary use of the Insert/Update/Delete procedures depending on if the datarow in the table is an Added, Modified or Deleted state